# "I have already put away some savings."

Tags: grammar

I'm a student in China and I read this in my textbook.

The whole sentence is:

> I have already put away some savings since I made a budget.

In my opinion, you can only "*put away a hundred dollars*" or "*put away some money*" and the money you put away will turn into your savings. Thus I think there's a mistake in my textbook. But since I'm not a native speaker, I want to know whether native speakers will use this phrase.

Comment: If you search google for the phrase "put away some savings" (with quotation marks) you also find many examples of this phrase in usage, also from several books, so yes, this is an acceptable phrase.

Answer (score 10):

Native speakers would definitely use this phrase. "Savings" refers to the money put away, and it can be identified as "savings" even before it reaches the savings account.

From a [google books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=put%20away%20savings#tbm=bks&q=%22put%20away%20savings%22), a [random example](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=akGmeu9C-G0C&pg=PA21&dq=%22put%20away%20savings%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22put%20away%20savings%22&f=false) is:

> And often, plans to put-away savings sooner are pushed back or delayed.

*Reference: The future of social security for this generation and the next: Current state of public opinion on the future of social security*

Comment: Note that "put [some money] away *into* savings" is also used, but that "put some savings away into savings" wouldn't.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and OP's sentence sounds a little off to me...anyone else? Is it saying "because I made a budget, I've put away savings", or " after I made my budget, I put away some savings".

Comment: @BruceWayne - I agree. I believe your latter suggestion is correct, and the sentence should have been written "I have already put away some savings since **making** a budget.